# programming in C: "expected constant expression" error in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qiNJWw5aLI) video tutorial on sorting arrays using C code. Unlike the video, which uses codeBlocks, I am using Visual Studio to compile/run my code. When attempting to run the following

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    
    int i,temp,swapped;
    int howMany = 10;
    int goals[howMany];

    
    return 0;

    }
```

I get the following error:

> Error 1   error C2057: expected constant expression   d:\temp\c tutorials\c tutorials\main.c  17  1   C Tutorials
>
> Error 2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    d:\temp\c tutorials\c tutorials\main.c  17  1   C Tutorials

I am using exactly the same code as on the video. Why will visual studio not allocate 10 bits of memory using the previously declared `howMany` variable?

Comment: You're using an old version of Visual Studio which does not have C99 support, and therefore does not support VLAs. Upgrade to VS2015 or newer, or switch to a better-supported C compiler, such as gcc.

Comment: In that case what is an alternate syntax I can use to accomplish the above? surely this older version still stupports dynamic array allocation...? I dont know how to do that in C

Comment: "*alternate*": If the `10` can be considered a fixed maximum, then outside `main()` do `#define GOALS_MAX (10)` and then define `int goals[GOALS_MAX];`

Comment: Since this is 2017 you really ought to be learning at least C99 (and preferably C11), so it really would be worth investing the effort into getting a more up-to-date compiler. Failing that, you can do dynamic memory allocation with [`malloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could allocate dynamically, use `malloc` or `calloc`. Note that by this way, you are allocating from the heap.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

const int howMany = 10;
int* goals = malloc(howMany * sizeof(int));
```

You should check the pointer in case `malloc` failed:

```
if (goals == NULL){
    /* Something went wrong, act accordingly */
} else{
    /* Move on in here, or just don't write the else part at all */
}
```

Then you can access this array by indexing:

```
goals[0] = 2017;
```

If you need to resize this array, you can use `realloc`. However while doing this, first use a new pointer and then check it again. Suppose you needed a bigger array in run-time. In this case, I will assume `howMany` wasn't declared as `const int` so it can be reassigned without some pointer hack.

```
howMany = 50;
int* temp_new_goals = realloc(goals, howMany * sizeof(int));
if (temp_new_goals == NULL){
    /* Something went wrong again */
} else{
    /* No problems, assign the new pointer. Don't worry, your old data remains still. */
    goals = temp_new_goals;
}
```

At the end, don't forget to `free` the memory you allocated. You don't want memory leaks:

```
free(goals);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define like this,

```
int goals[10];
```

Or you can modify `howMany` to `const` like this,

```
const int howMany = 10;
```

Or you can define `howMany` as a macro outside like this,

```
#define howMany 10
```

Comment: "*Or you can modify howMany to const like this,

`const int howMany = 10;`*" Did you test this? It does not compile.

Comment: "*...  it works.*": Did you use a C compiler? Probably not, but a C++ compiler.

Comment: I tested using Visual Studio, the same with asker, why should you only want a C compiler?

Comment: "*why should you only want a C compiler*" Because the question is tagged C not C++. Those are two different languages. VS by default uses a C++ compiler. To have it us a C compiler you need to set this explicitly on project level. The code in question would not compile using a (standard conforming) C compiler.

Comment: ...err, because the question is tagged C not C++.  Besides since VC++ 2015, the original code works when C compilation is used, but remains invalid C++.

Comment: @Clifford: I am referring to VS12 in C mode and the code `const int howMany = 10; int goals[howMany];`

Comment: @alk : You need only name the source file with a .c extension to use C compilation - no project settings required.

Comment: "*file with a .c extension to use C*" Well this didn't work for VS10. I am unsure for newer version. If it does now, then fine. But this was not my point.

Comment: @alk : My ...err comment was not addressed to you; we simply posted the same comment to Harrison.

Comment: @alk : Sure it works in VS2010. Though not perhaps if you explicitly force C++ compilation at the project level.